# How to create Emoji layout like in WhatsApp - Android

Tags: android, emoji, whatsapp

Can anyone tell me how to create custom emoji layout like in **WhatsApp** without using any **libraries**.

Thanks in advance !

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X97YY.png)

Answer (score 1):

This is an emoji keyboard. You can configure it in the settings of an Android phone. Its not built by WhatsApp.